# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());


TextBox textname=          ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[1])).Text;

            TextBox textdob = (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[1]))).Text;

            TextBox textrole = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)(((System.Web.UI.Control)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[1])))))).SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

Getting that error TextBox textname
                   Textbox textdob
                   Textbox text

Comment: Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31921524/edit) and add the markup code of `GridView1`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
textname.Text = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)(((System.Web.UI.Control)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[1])))))).SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

you can`t add a string to the textbox itself

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following line of code

```
TextBox textname = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[1])).Text;
```

`((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[1])).Text` is a string, but you're assigning it to `textname`, which is a `TextBox`, so that's why you got the error.

Change the above code to below

```
TextBox textname = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[1]);
```

then you can get the text this way

```
string name = txtname.Text;
```

The same thing applies to the second textbox

```
TextBox textdob = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[1]);

// get the dob
string dbo = textdob.Text;
```

For the dropdownlist, you have to assign it to a `DropDownList` instead of a `TextBox`

```
DropDownList ddlRole = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[1]);

// get the selected index
int selectedRoleIndex = ddlRole.SelectedIndex;
```